# QT: setStyleSheet from a resource QSS file?

Tags: qt

In my widget, I can do something like that:

```
MyWindow::MyWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent)
{
    ui.setupUi(this);
    setStyleSheet("QWidget { background-color: red }");  // <--- HERE
}
```

This will set the widget background red.

I have a QSS file in my resources. How do I instruct my widget to take its style sheet content from there, vs just taking the qss syntax as parameter?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Got it: you actually have to "read the file" from the resources, convert it to a QString and feed it to the setStyleSheet. E.g.:

> ```
> QFile file(":/qss/default.qss");
> file.open(QFile::ReadOnly);
> QString styleSheet = QLatin1String(file.readAll());
> setStyleSheet(styleSheet);
> ```

Comment: But don't forget to call ensurePolished() otherwise the new stylesheet may not be applied.

Comment: what is ensurePolished for?

Comment: @ffttyy This ensures that the new style is actually applied to the widgets. I had cases where the new style wasn't applied otherwise.

Answer (score 28):

As an alternative to setting a style sheet for each widget, you can just load and set a stylesheet for a whole application. Something like this:

```
QApplication app( argc, argv );

// Load an application style
QFile styleFile( ":/style.qss" );
styleFile.open( QFile::ReadOnly );

// Apply the loaded stylesheet
QString style( styleFile.readAll() );
app.setStyleSheet( style );
```

In this case all widgets will pick their styles from the given stylesheet automatically.